# Laravel QueryException / SQLSTATE[42S02]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, web

I'm new to Laravel and have an error.
When I try to check my page, I get this error:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 713: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db_tcc.colaboradors' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from colaboradors order by id_colaborador asc)

My table name is 'colaboradores', I know the error is 'colaboradors', but I dont know where is that 'colaboradors' in my project files.
I need to find in the code to fix, but I dont have idea what file take care of sql in laravel.

My model for colaboradores:

```php
<?php
    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    class Colaborador extends Model {
        protected $fillable = array('id_colaborador','nome','rg','orgao_expedidor','cpf','estado_civil','sexo','nome_pai','nome_mae','natura‌​lidade','data_nascimento','login','senha','siape','pis','rua','numero','bairro',‌​'cidade','estado','cep','telefone_fixo','telefone_celular','telefone_comercial','email');
    }
```

My controller : http://pastebin.com/QYgRBRrc

Comment: Do you have a model for colaboradores?

Comment: Yes            <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 

class Colaborador extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('id_colaborador', 'nome', 'rg','orgao_expedidor','cpf','estado_civil','sexo','nome_pai','nome_mae','naturalidade',
        'data_nascimento','login','senha','siape','pis','rua','numero','bairro','cidade','estado','cep','telefone_fixo',
        'telefone_celular','telefone_comercial','email');
}

Comment: Is there nothing in model like  protected $table = 'colaboradors'; ?

Comment: no, my model dont have. thats my controller.   http://pastebin.com/QYgRBRrc

Comment: Usually it is specified in model that which table to use.

Comment: what version of laravel you using?

Comment: I deleted my answer as laravel adds a plural 's' to the table name if it not specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The "snake case", plural name of the class will be used as  the table
>   name unless another name is explicitly specified.

So this is your issue.

You have two options:

- Either rename your model class or
- Add in your model $table = 'colaboradores';

Comment: Thanks bro!!! I add in my model "protected $table = 'colaboradores';" and it works!

Comment: Good to hear, please accept the answer so other looking for same know what worked.